# Как исправить сжимание текста в span?

Tags: css, html5

У меня есть вот такая структура:

```
<li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="Главная">
        <span class="span-menu">ГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавная</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Я хочу увести в троеточие длинный текст, для этого оборачиваю его в span и задаю следующие свойства:

```
.span-menu {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Но текст перекрывается сверху, и не выводится полностью.

[image: Как оно выводится.]

Весь код:

```css
.link {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B7B7B7;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.10);
  transition: .2s;
}

.item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="Главная">
      <span class="span-menu">ГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавнаяГлавная</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="............">............</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="............">............</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="............">............</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link" title="............">............</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: У вас размер шрифта больше чем максимальная высота текста...

Comment: Шрифт у меня задан в 18px, а высоту текста я не ограничивал. Я пробовал закомментить .span-menu, тогда текст встаёт как нужно, но он не уводится в троеточие, что логично.

Comment: А где стили остальных элементов? Какие глобальные стили используются? Код выше нормально отображает текст при `40px` и проблем никаких нет.

Comment: При 40 px, он становится больше, но пропадает ровно половина. Сейчас обновлю код.

Comment: `line-height: 1.2%;` -- при размере шрифта `18px` это `line-height: 0.216667px`.

Comment: Всем спасибо, сделал так и всё заработало.
В `span-menu` добавил `line-height: normal;`